# not a function error in jquery when click on second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am getting a problem in wordpress plugin. I have made a image area map which is located at the location.

http://singhalcompetitionclasses.com/newspaper/

In this I have created two area maps.

When I click first time on any area map, then it shows the pop up

but when I again click on the any of the area map then it gives error in console

`hello is not a function`

I am using the code as follow :

```
<script>
function hello(id){ 
        var path = "<?php echo $path; ?>";
        alert(id);
        var path = path+id+'/'+id+'.jpg';
        image = "<img src='"+path+"' id='hello'>";
        //alert(image);
        jQuery("#hidden").html(image);
         var newwindow = window.open(jQuery(this).prop('href'), '', 'height=800,width=800');
       // if (window.focus) {
            newwindow.focus();
            newwindow.document.write( jQuery("#hidden").html() );
        //}
        return false;
    }
</script>

<div style="width: 900px; overflow: scroll; float: left;">
<img src="<?php echo $img_src;?>" id="photo" style="width: 850px;" usemap="#planetmap" />
</div>
<map name="planetmap">
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("select * from epaper");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $xx = $row['file_id'];
    echo '<area shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer;" coords="'.$row['x1'].','.$row['y1'].','.$row['x2'].','.$row['y2'].'" target="_blank" onclick="return hello('.$xx.');" alt="Sun" onmouseover="borderit(this,"black")" onmouseout="borderit(this,"white")">';
}
?>
<div id="hidden" style="display:none;">

</div>
</map>
```

Please guys help me to come out of the problem

Comment: can you somehow add a demo

Comment: Yep added the website link : http://singhalcompetitionclasses.com/newspaper/

Comment: There are more javascript errors to solve first. And by the look at what's loaded on the page regarding JavaScript, I see too many versions of jQuery.

Comment: I have removed the anohter versions of jquery but getting the same problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function name is used as id of an html element inside it. It confuse the browser.

Change the id on this line:

`image = "<img src='"+path+"' id='hello'>";`

to (example):

`image = "<img src='"+path+"' id='other_id'>";`

Answer (score 1):

```html
I have checked the coded there is string error you can use below code:
I hope this is fine for you:-

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $xx = $row['file_id'];
    ?>
        <area shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer;" coords="<?php echo $row['x1'].','.$row['y1'].','.$row['x2'].','.$row['y2']; ?>" target="_blank" onclick="return hello('<?php echo $xx; ?>');" alt="Sun" onmouseover="borderit(this,'black')" onmouseout="borderit(this,'white')">
    <?php   }  ?>

OR

echo '<area shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer;" coords="'.$row['x1'].','.$row['y1'].','.$row['x2'].','.$row['y2'].'" target="_blank" onclick="return hello('.$xx.');" alt="Sun" onmouseover="borderit(this,\'black\')" onmouseout="borderit(this,\'white\')">';
```

Comment: Hello Pukhraj, I have updated the code on website but still getting the same error